# How to find efficiently if a tuple is a subset of another

Tags: python, subset

I know about the `set` implementation which is great. However, it has a huge limitation: it can't deal with repetition of an item.

Let's work with integers:

```
tuple1 = (100, 100, 375)
layer = [(100, 100, 100, 375), (20, 100, 100, 375), (20, 20, 100, 375), (20, 20, 20, 375), (20, 20, 30, 375), (20, 20, 40, 375), (20, 20, 50, 375), (20, 20, 60, 375), (20, 20, 70, 375), (20, 20, 80, 375), (20, 30, 100, 375), (20, 30, 30, 375), (20, 30, 40, 375), (20, 30, 50, 375), (20, 30, 60, 375), (20, 30, 70, 375), (20, 30, 80, 375), (20, 40, 100, 375), (20, 40, 40, 375), (20, 40, 50, 375), (20, 40, 60, 375), (20, 40, 70, 375), (20, 40, 80, 375), (20, 50, 100, 375), (20, 50, 50, 375), (20, 50, 60, 375), (20, 50, 70, 375), (20, 50, 80, 375), (20, 60, 100, 375), (20, 60, 60, 375), (20, 60, 70, 375), (20, 60, 80, 375), (20, 70, 100, 375), (20, 70, 70, 375), (20, 70, 80, 375), (20, 80, 100, 375), (20, 80, 80, 375), (30, 100, 100, 375), (30, 30, 100, 375), (30, 30, 30, 375), (30, 30, 40, 375), (30, 30, 50, 375), (30, 30, 60, 375), (30, 30, 70, 375), (30, 30, 80, 375), (30, 40, 100, 375), (30, 40, 40, 375), (30, 40, 50, 375), (30, 40, 60, 375), (30, 40, 70, 375), (30, 40, 80, 375), (30, 50, 100, 375), (30, 50, 50, 375), (30, 50, 60, 375), (30, 50, 70, 375), (30, 50, 80, 375), (30, 60, 100, 375), (30, 60, 60, 375), (30, 60, 70, 375), (30, 60, 80, 375), (30, 70, 100, 375), (30, 70, 70, 375), (30, 70, 80, 375), (30, 80, 100, 100), (30, 80, 100, 375), (30, 80, 80, 375), (40, 100, 100, 375), (40, 40, 100, 375), (40, 40, 40, 375), (40, 40, 50, 375), (40, 40, 60, 375), (40, 40, 70, 375), (40, 40, 80, 375), (40, 50, 100, 375), (40, 50, 50, 375), (40, 50, 60, 375), (40, 50, 70, 375), (40, 50, 80, 375), (40, 60, 100, 375), (40, 60, 60, 375), (40, 60, 70, 375), (40, 60, 80, 375), (40, 70, 100, 375), (40, 70, 70, 375), (40, 70, 80, 375), (40, 80, 100, 375), (40, 80, 80, 375), (50, 100, 100, 375), (50, 50, 100, 375), (50, 50, 50, 375), (50, 50, 60, 375), (50, 50, 70, 375), (50, 50, 80, 375), (50, 50, 80, 80), (50, 60, 100, 375), (50, 60, 60, 375), (50, 60, 70, 375), (50, 60, 80, 375), (50, 70, 100, 375), (50, 70, 70, 375), (50, 70, 70, 80), (50, 70, 80, 375), (50, 80, 100, 375), (50, 80, 80, 375), (50, 80, 80, 80), (60, 100, 100, 375), (60, 60, 100, 375), (60, 60, 60, 375), (60, 60, 70, 375), (60, 60, 80, 375), (60, 70, 100, 375), (60, 70, 70, 375), (60, 70, 80, 375), (60, 80, 100, 375), (60, 80, 80, 375), (60, 80, 80, 80), (70, 100, 100, 375), (70, 70, 100, 375), (70, 70, 70, 375), (70, 70, 80, 375), (70, 80, 100, 100), (70, 80, 100, 375), (70, 80, 80, 375), (80, 100, 100, 375), (80, 80, 100, 375), (80, 80, 80, 100), (80, 80, 80, 375)]
```

I want to keep the items in `layer` which are not made from a subset of `tuple1`. i.e. for instance, the 2 first ones must be left off.

Right now I'm using a `for` loop:

```
new_layer = list()
for elt in layer:
    copy = list(elt)
    for x in tuple1:
        if x in copy:
            copy.remove(x)
    if len(copy) == 1:
        continue
    else:
        new_layer.append(elt)
```

There gonna be a better solution than this... Moreover the final problem is actually more complex.

I have 5 layers:

- layer1: elements of `len`: 2
- layer2: elements of `len`: 3
- layer3: elements of `len`: 4
- layer4: elements of `len`: 5
- layer5: elements of `len`: 6

The goal is to get rid in the layer `N` of the elements which derives (are made from a subset) of the layer `N-k`.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you think it's too broad, could you add a comment? The goal is to find the elements of `layer1` which do not include `tuple1` as a subset.

Comment: _it can't deal with repetition of an item_... sets are made specifically to not contain duplicates.

Comment: @Eldelshell Yes that I know. And they are extremely handy when it comes to finding subset in larger elements. But you can't use them with elements in which items are repeated. Thus, I was looking for another solution more elegant and performant than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, subclassing [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and implementing `__contains__` (for the `in` operator):

```
from collections import Counter
class TupleCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, t):
        super().__init__(t)

    def __contains__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            other = self.__class__(other)

        for (v,c) in other.items():
            if self.get(v,0) < c:
                return False

        return True
```

Example:

```
needle = (100, 100, 375)
layer = [(100, 100, 100, 375), (20, 100, 100, 375), (20, 20, 100, 375), (20, 20, 20, 375), (20, 20, 30, 375), (20, 20, 40, 375), (20, 20, 50, 375), (20, 20, 60, 375), (20, 20, 70, 375), (20, 20, 80, 375), (20, 30, 100, 375), (20, 30, 30, 375), (20, 30, 40, 375), (20, 30, 50, 375), (20, 30, 60, 375), (20, 30, 70, 375), (20, 30, 80, 375), (20, 40, 100, 375), (20, 40, 40, 375), (20, 40, 50, 375), (20, 40, 60, 375), (20, 40, 70, 375), (20, 40, 80, 375), (20, 50, 100, 375), (20, 50, 50, 375), (20, 50, 60, 375), (20, 50, 70, 375), (20, 50, 80, 375), (20, 60, 100, 375), (20, 60, 60, 375), (20, 60, 70, 375), (20, 60, 80, 375), (20, 70, 100, 375), (20, 70, 70, 375), (20, 70, 80, 375), (20, 80, 100, 375), (20, 80, 80, 375), (30, 100, 100, 375), (30, 30, 100, 375), (30, 30, 30, 375), (30, 30, 40, 375), (30, 30, 50, 375), (30, 30, 60, 375), (30, 30, 70, 375), (30, 30, 80, 375), (30, 40, 100, 375), (30, 40, 40, 375), (30, 40, 50, 375), (30, 40, 60, 375), (30, 40, 70, 375), (30, 40, 80, 375), (30, 50, 100, 375), (30, 50, 50, 375), (30, 50, 60, 375), (30, 50, 70, 375), (30, 50, 80, 375), (30, 60, 100, 375), (30, 60, 60, 375), (30, 60, 70, 375), (30, 60, 80, 375), (30, 70, 100, 375), (30, 70, 70, 375), (30, 70, 80, 375), (30, 80, 100, 100), (30, 80, 100, 375), (30, 80, 80, 375), (40, 100, 100, 375), (40, 40, 100, 375), (40, 40, 40, 375), (40, 40, 50, 375), (40, 40, 60, 375), (40, 40, 70, 375), (40, 40, 80, 375), (40, 50, 100, 375), (40, 50, 50, 375), (40, 50, 60, 375), (40, 50, 70, 375), (40, 50, 80, 375), (40, 60, 100, 375), (40, 60, 60, 375), (40, 60, 70, 375), (40, 60, 80, 375), (40, 70, 100, 375), (40, 70, 70, 375), (40, 70, 80, 375), (40, 80, 100, 375), (40, 80, 80, 375), (50, 100, 100, 375), (50, 50, 100, 375), (50, 50, 50, 375), (50, 50, 60, 375), (50, 50, 70, 375), (50, 50, 80, 375), (50, 50, 80, 80), (50, 60, 100, 375), (50, 60, 60, 375), (50, 60, 70, 375), (50, 60, 80, 375), (50, 70, 100, 375), (50, 70, 70, 375), (50, 70, 70, 80), (50, 70, 80, 375), (50, 80, 100, 375), (50, 80, 80, 375), (50, 80, 80, 80), (60, 100, 100, 375), (60, 60, 100, 375), (60, 60, 60, 375), (60, 60, 70, 375), (60, 60, 80, 375), (60, 70, 100, 375), (60, 70, 70, 375), (60, 70, 80, 375), (60, 80, 100, 375), (60, 80, 80, 375), (60, 80, 80, 80), (70, 100, 100, 375), (70, 70, 100, 375), (70, 70, 70, 375), (70, 70, 80, 375), (70, 80, 100, 100), (70, 80, 100, 375), (70, 80, 80, 375), (80, 100, 100, 375), (80, 80, 100, 375), (80, 80, 80, 100), (80, 80, 80, 375)]

needle = TupleCounter(needle)
filtered = [t for t in layer if needle in TupleCounter(t)]
print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
[(100, 100, 100, 375), 
 (20, 100, 100, 375), 
 (30, 100, 100, 375), 
 (40, 100, 100, 375), 
 (50, 100, 100, 375), 
 (60, 100, 100, 375), 
 (70, 100, 100, 375), 
 (80, 100, 100, 375)
]
```

Edit: Note that this only cares about the frequency of values in the tuple, and not their relative position inside it.  So, it'll also match (375,100,100), even though the elements of the tuple are in reverse order.

Comment: Great, I actually don't care about the order, so it's even better :) Thanks! I'll test this!

Comment: Ok, so it works perfectly and it's great. However, and it's been a long time, I've got no clue how it works. What is `super()`? `other` is a dict? What is `self.get()` calling? Where is the counting with the Counter done? I would love to learn a bit more on the implementation since there is a lot of new stuff for me in that one!

Comment: From what I get, `__contains__` will implement the `in` operator, as a `__eq__` does for the `==`, but I actually don't understand what is performed to declared an element `in` another.

Comment: You're correct about `__contains__`.  In this case, that method does two things.  (1) makes sure that `x` in `x in y` is *also* a TupleCounter object (if not, it creates one), and (2) compares the number of times each element in "self" appears to the number of time each element in "other" appears.  `Counter`, the class you're subclassing might be worth looking into.

Comment: I already used `Counter`, I'm quite familiar with it. It's the idea of subclassing that sound funny. I need to look more into it, anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh when you subclass you transmit the structure of Counter! Python is so handy x')